# What is the difference between lists and checklists?

Tags: lists

I found this material online but I did not understand the difference between lists and checklists.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is any set of items that are separated between commas, semicolons, or slashes.

> "commas, semicolons, or slashes"

This is a list, as it separates the three items (can be more) with commas in this case. Whenever you make a list, you **must** keep the same styling between the items.

This is a correct list:

> "I am going to go skiing, hiking, and swimming."

This list is correct because all items have the same form. **verb + -ing**

This is an incorrect list:

> "I am going to go hiking, invite my friends, and prepare for my test."

This list is incorrect because it has 3 different forms. These are:

> 1. **verb + ing**
> 2. **infinitive - to**
> 3. **phrasal verb**

If you create an incorrect list, there is no parallel structure, which must be maintained when creating a list for it to be a correct sentence.

A checklist on the other hand is a to-do list, usually containing a few short notes to help you remember what to do.

Comment: Can a list be enumerated?

Comment: Yes. I need to:
1. Do my homework.
2. Eat dinner.
3. Brush my teeth.

Comment: That's an example of checklist ?

Comment: Well, yes, essentially.

During the weekend, my friends and I are going to go swim, play tennis, make our homework.

That previous sentence is a list.

The checklist:
GROCERIES

Bananas,
Apples,
Snacks,
Drinks

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Block quotes are for direct quotations and require citations.

Comment: Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a list, you enumerate or compile things. On the picture in your post, you can see a list.

A checklist is a list of the tasks to do, the things to buy, the people to call, an inventory, etc. You will probably add a check whenever one of the items is done.

You could consult a dictionary to find out the difference.

(My sources: en.wiktionary.org/wiki/checklist#Noun / en.wiktionary.org/wiki/list#Noun [4th definition])

Comment: Can you support your contentions? If so, edit that support into this answer, and please include source citations.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not Wikipedia here, but I am willing to provide you sources.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/checklist#Noun
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/list#Noun (4th definition)
Also, any good dictionary should help.

Comment: FWIW, I think it is a great thing to provide supporting citations, but it really isn't necessary here: the questioner could have readily found the answer to this question by simply looking in a dictionary. Really, this one should be moved to ESL rather than being answered here.

Comment: Assertions supported by citation to established authority is conventional here at ELU. Take a look at other answers that have garnered positive votes.

Comment: There is no picture in your post. If you mean the image in the above post can you specify that, as I read this as there being a picture missing in your post.

Comment: @Fraser Orr - Yes, this is a GR question, but it won't be migrated, more probably closed. But Archa choose to answer this OP, here. My advise was sound, and conventional. It was intended to assist both the OP & the responding user. It applies to any answer at ELU.

Comment: I just edited my answer so that it's more conventional.

Comment: I'm hoping, Archa, only that you'll adhere to the communities conventions. I hope the substance of your questions and answers will be anything but conventional. Thanks, I wasn't meaning to harass you.

Comment: Sorry for my rudeness.